# How to construct a puppet resource from Python

Tags: python, puppet

I would like to construct a puppet resource from within Python. If I had a hash of keys and values, or variables with values, how could this be done?

This is a simple example of a puppet resource.

```
file { '/etc/passwd':
  owner => root,
  group => root,
  mode  => 644
}
```

If I had the string `/etc/passwd`, variable with a value of `root`, another variable with a value of `root`, and a variable `mode` with a value of `644`, how would I generate the above resource from within Python?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by a "manifest entry"?

Comment: It appears he means resource. Funny thing is I have already implemented something like this in ruby, but it is part of a much more sophisticated forthcoming software.

Comment: Given a bunch of variables and their values, I want to be able to construct a puppet "resource declaration" from within Python. Resource declarations are put into puppet manifests, that's why I called it a manifest entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment it seems you just want to be able to output your python objects into puppet manifest format.  Since there is not a python package that does this I propose writing your own classes to handle the resource types you need, then overriding the **str** function so that it outputs the manifest you need.

```
class fileresource:

    def __init__(self, mfile, owner, group, mode):
        self.mfile = mfile
        self.owner = owner
        self.group = group
        self.mode = mode

    def __str__(self):
        mystring = "file {'" + self.mfile + "':\n"
        mystring += "  owner => " + self.owner + "\n"
        mystring += "  group => " + self.group + "\n"
        mystring += "  mode => " + self.mode + "\n"
        mystring += "}\n"
        return mystring

if __name__ == "__main__":
    myfile = fileresource("/etc/passwd", "root", "root", "0644")
    print myfile
```

This would be the output:

```
$ python fileresource.py 
file {'/etc/passwd':
  owner => root
  group => root
  mode => 0644
}
```

You could conceivably write an entire package that handles all the different types of puppet resources and use this in your code.  Hopefully, this is what you are looking for.